# Weapon follow player hand in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, transform

I really need some help in making a weapon pickup in unity 2D. Well, When I copy the camera follow script than edited it to make the weapon follow a point which is the player's hand but in condition to do it the player needs to be close to the weapon and press a button but the problem is that it transform to the hand point position only when I press the button and then stop I want it to follow the hand point all the time after pressing the button, any help plz guys any help is appreciated. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the weapon child of the hand. So weapon will automatically follow it.

```
YourWeapon.transform.SetParent(YourHand.transform);
```

Also see: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html?_ga=2.191524899.841743980.1600544710-1554071575.1600544710